# AngularJS: Changing the title attribute using ng-class?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class

I currently have an image updating on my web page depending on something else that has been selected from a dropdown by the user.

```
<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon" title="test" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok' : user.StatusID == 1, 'glyphicon-remove' : user.StatusID == 2, 'glyphicon-lock' : user.StatusID == 3}"></span></td>
```

As you can see the title says "test", but i want this to say a different message for whatever image is currently showing this. Using angular, what would be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td align="center"><span class="glyphicon" title={{mymsg}} ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok' : user.StatusID == 1, 'glyphicon-remove' : user.StatusID == 2, 'glyphicon-lock' : user.StatusID == 3}"></span></td>
```

controller.js:

```
$scope.mymsg="Hello How are you";
```